# Convert a base25 String to binary String in Java

Tags: java, binary

So I have a set of base digits like "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ34679"

how do I convert a value say "D6CN96W6WT" to binary string in Java?

Comment: That's an unussual set of digits, I doubt highly there's anything built-in to handle it.

Comment: What are the characters in your binary system? Y and N?

Comment: You'll need a table mapping these characters to their decimal equivalents.

Normally, for bases greater than 10, you'd use a set of consecutive characters. You don't need a table then -- order implies value. For base 25, characters 0-9, A-O would be the common choice.

Comment: The table in this case would be, presumably, 'B'=0, 'C'=1, 'D'=2, 'F'=3, ... , '7'=23, '9'=24

Answer (score 6):

This should work (assuming 0,1 for you binary digits):

```
// your arbitrary digits
private static final String DIGITS = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ34679";

public String base25ToBinary(String base25Number) {
    long value = 0;
    char[] base25Digits = base25Number.toCharArray();

    for (char digit : base25Digits) {
        value = value * 25 + DIGITS.indexOf(digit);
    }

    return Long.toString(value, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, for base-25 strings.

```
Integer.toString(Integer.valueof(base25str, 25), 2)
```

Its a little unclear from your question whether you're talking about actual 0-9-Z bases, or a number encoding with an arbitrary list of symbols.  I'm assuming the first, if its the later then you're out of luck on built-ins.

Comment: For long values, you can use `Long` instead of `Integer`

Comment: unfortunately, it was a random list of symbols